# Redis pub/sub with database

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I'm new to Redis.
In my app, I have several servers, and I want to use Redis to share updates between them. My idea is that each server will subscribe to a certain channel in the Redis instance and in addition will be able to publish messages for that channel.
In addition to the publish/subscribe mechanics, I want to store data in Redis (that is, use Redis's database capabilities).

My question is whether it is correct to create 3 instances on each server -

1. Subscriber
2. Publisher
3. dataHandler

```
const dataStoreHandler = Redis.createClient({url:process.env.REDIS_URL});
const subscriber = Redis.createClient({url:process.env.REDIS_URL});
const publisher = Redis.createClient({url:process.env.REDIS_URL});
```

Or maybe it is more correct to create a publisher and a subscriber and one of them will also handle database operations (get.set, .etc)

Comment: I don't see a reason to have more than 1 client handling everything.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. It seems that subscriber and publisher are not able to handle get/set operations.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38705951/err-only-psubscribe-punsubscribe-ping-quit-allowed-in-this-context

Comment: Is that so? I didn't know that. If that's the case, then you don't have much choice. Anyway, you should always aim at the lowest number of clients possible.